# Magento session cookie, form keys not working correctly. (magento 1.8.1)

Tags: magento, session, caching, session-cookies, magento-1.8

For some reason, after debugging i've noticed that form_keys are valid only after i clear the cache by doing a manual `rm -rf *` in the `var` folder, clearing my browser cache and retrying the site.

I have made no changes to the core code, I've diffed it to the original 1.8.1 installation, and they are exactly the same.

The original problem I had was that customers couldn't login because I had been using  a `customer/persistent/login.phtml` file from the 1.7.0.2 version, and had to change it to add the `form_key` as a hidden input element using the method shown in all other posts about the new addition of form keys in magento 1.8.1.

I had captcha enabled, and for some reason when I went to the customer login, captcha isn't displayed.

Randomly, I don't know what I did, the page refreshed, and the captcha displayed and I was able to login to the dashboard and it worked.  Then I logged out, and the same problem happened, the customer logs in with the correct username/password, but is redirected to the same customer login page.

I have debugged the `loginPostAction` in `AccountController.php` from `app/code/core/mage/customer/controllers`, and it appears that when the form key is valid, after refreshing cache, clearing cache, in mage and the browser,  it reaches `if( getIsJustConfirmed == true){ go to __welcomedashboard(..) }` however `getIsJustConfirmed` returns `null` or `false`.

I did a check to see where `getIsJustConfirmed` is set, and it appears in `setCustomer` of the `Session.php` inside `app/code/core/mage/customer/Session.php`:

```
public function setCustomer(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer)
    {
        // check if customer is not confirmed
        if ($customer->isConfirmationRequired()) {
            if ($customer->getConfirmation()) {
                return $this->_logout();
            }
        }
        $this->_customer = $customer;
        $this->setId($customer->getId());
        // save customer as confirmed, if it is not
        if ((!$customer->isConfirmationRequired()) && $customer->getConfirmation()) {
            $customer->setConfirmation(null)->save();
            $customer->setIsJustConfirmed(true);
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

the first part of `!$customer->isConfirmationRequired()` always returns `true`, however `$customer-->getConfirmation()` returns `null`, so it doesn't `setIsJustConfirmed(true)`.

Answer (score 3):

As you've noticed, Magento 1.8 adds form keys to a whole lot of forms.  The form key in the hidden input field needs to match the form key in your user's session.  This plays havoc with any form of caching, as the form key stored in the block or full page cache is unlikely to match the user's session key.

Firstly, I'll assume you've already compared the templates you've copied into a custom theme against the base/default versions and added form keys wherever they're missing.

Then, the next suggestion is to turn all caching in Magento off (and any full page caches such as Varnish) and see if that resolves the problem.  This will confirm that you're caching form keys somewhere and this is the cause of your problem.

Next, use a tool like Fabrizio's Advanced Template Hints to see if any of the templates containing a form key are being cached, either explicitly or implicitly via a parent block.  If so, this is the cause of your problem, and you'll need to investigate what is causing these blocks to be cached.  A stock Magento system won't cache these blocks, but a 3rd party extension might be causing it.

Finally, once the block cache is resolved, you'll need to think about full pace caching (if used).  There's no easy answers here, you'll need to either not cache the affected pages in a FPC, or find a way to put the correct form key into the page after it's served.

Answer (score 1):

Step-by-step, I was having the same issue. I started logging the session key output by `Mage::log(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey());` on each page load.

Until attempting to login as a customer, the session remained consistent.
However, *after* attempting to log-in, I determined that the session was getting invalidated on each page load (i.e. the aforementioned logging method echoed a different form key on each page load).

This led me to the cookie. I noticed that after attempting to log in as a customer, there were two `frontend` cookies stored by the browser: one with `.my_domain.com` and another with just `my_domain.com`, thereby causing the invalidation.

Setting the cookie Domain under `System -> Configuration -> General -> Web` to `my_domain.com` addressed the duplicate cookie problem and the forms behaved as expected.